# My Python/Beautifulsoup csv output prints table data both vertically and horizontally

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, output

My issue is that I only want the data to be printed vertically, but the data is also printed horizontally on the same line. Is there something subtle in the code that I forgot to address? Thanks!

```
import csv
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs


sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('URL')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'html.parser')

table = soup.findAll('table')[7]
table_rows = table.findAll('tr')


for tr in table_rows:
    playerdata = ""
    td = tr.findAll('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)

headers = [th.text.encode("utf-8") for th in table.select("tr th")]

with open("final80.csv","a") as f:
            wr = csv.writer(f)
            wr.writerow(headers)
            wr.writerows([[td.text.encode("utf-8") for td in row.findAll("td")] for row in table.select("tr + tr")])


And the output comes out as: 
Header1 Header2 1 2 3 4
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: when you say `printed horizontally`, it's in the csv file output or in the console ?

Comment: It's in the console as well. Thanks!

Comment: ok but your edited question already output each row vertically, i'm not sure about how you want to split a row ? maybe add a short example of the table input

Comment: Add the parameter `newline=''` to your `open()`